# How to work with objects and lists in python?

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to use the [pyscal](https://pyscal.org/en/latest/) module to read "trajectory" files which contain positions of atoms in molecules at different time steps. **I want to be able to analyze all of the positions of all of the atoms in each molecule at each timestep. How do I do this?** I guess this problem has to do with how to use objects and lists in python. The following example creates a pyscal `System` object that reads atom 0 (in molecule 0) at timestep 0:

```
from pyscal import Trajectory
traj = Trajectory(filename)
sl = traj[0]
sys = sl.to_system()
sys[0].atoms[0].pos
```

And the positions are given as output:

```
[36.0, 78.0, 96.0]
```

I figured out I can also find which molecule atom 0 in timestep 0 belongs to by the following:

```
sys = sl.to_system(customkeys=["mol"])
sys[0].atoms[0].custom["mol"]
```

which correctly outputs `0`. Now I want to output the positions for all atoms in each molecule at each timestep. For timestep 0, I can do something like this by:

```
for i in range(1000):
    s = sys[0].atoms[i].pos
    print(s)
```

But this is painfully slow, seems to output a separate array with each print statement, and also requires that I know a priori the number of atoms in each molecule (here, 1000). I'd appreciate if somebody can guide me here.

Comment: [SO] isn't really suitable for personal training and guidance. You might want to take a look at the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and similar learning resources instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you have object that can be iterated over (an iterable), you can use that itself in your for-loop, rather than using `range`.

So, you should be able to do this

```py
for atom in sys[0].atoms: #within the loop, we will have a variable called atom that is iterating sequentially through every atom within sys[0].atoms
    s = atom.pos
    # do more stuff
```

I'm not sure what exactly is wanted/needed regarding your printing and what your arrays look like, not sure I can help on that even if I understand it better.

Comment: Thank you. I realized I could access all of the slices of the list via something like `ml = traj[:]`. Is there a similar way to do this for all of the atoms at a timestep? `sys[0].atoms[:].pos` doesn't work. I guess this isn't a list per se?

Comment: What is `sys[0].atoms[0].pos` known as so I can look it up and learn how to use it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about `sys[0].atoms[0].pos`. I actually have no idea what pyscal is or know anything about atoms, I just know a little bit about how lists work in python. You may be able to do something like in your first comment here by creating a new empty list `l = list()` and then in the for-loop adding each thing to that list. It would be `l.append(atom.pos)`, and at the end of that you'd have a list `l` that has `n` items, each on a `pos` from an `atom`.